# Question about the work culture in the USA when it comes to sole proprietorship (trading) - job hopping

Tags: job-change

In the U.S. job market, more specifically in the sectors where the average I.Q. as defined by the WAIS-IV is likely on average one standard deviation above the norm (for example tech, finance, upper-level retail management) will potential employers be bothered if you are a part-time self-employed *derivatives trader* more specifically *seasonal options trader* (with some formal proof of your skills via a reputable broker and a base capital of 25k $) who feels comfortable making profits in certain market trends/periods.

I am asking primarily because I am interest in finding a country where the job-market is more fast-paced and I can adapt my trading life to specific market trends while having little trouble finding "regular" (let's just say programming / data analysis) jobs for periods where I don't feel as comfortable working the market in a solo manner.

Comment: What kind of retail trading are you talking about?  Are you talking day trading of stocks, or running a food truck or what?  If you're asking for your own purposes, then making it a bit more specific would help clarify, and get better answers.  If you're not asking for your own purposes... why are you asking?

Comment: Are you IN America at the moment? If not. that will be your hardest hurdle. Also, take very good advice before messing with options trading unless you can afford to lose a lot more than your $25K.

Comment: It's not "illegal" in any way. There are no regulations.  It would be seen as incredibly silly / immature.

Comment: I cleared up the question and made it more focused, hopefully it works now.

Comment: This sounds like a convoluted way of asking if US employers are going to question someone that hops in and out of the job market.  Ultimately Yes. Unless you are just wanting to work low end jobs like starbucks or mcdonalds then they are going to want to see some level of stability and dedication to the position. Literally anyone that shows they will hang around and become invested in the company would be better than taking the time to train someone that is just going to leave on a whim.

Comment: "more specifically in the sectors where the average I.Q. as defined by the WAIS-IV is likely on average one standard deviation above the norm (for example tech, finance, upper-level retail management)" I work in Tech myself, so take this in the best possible way, but this is a super arrogant thing to say. And when I hear something like that, I assume that the person who said it is super insecure about their own self and would probably piss off all of his future co-workers because of that.

Comment: @ Stephan Branczyk    I am sorry I didn't mean to come off rude, just robotic and sterile so as to be as clear as possible (since I am new), so I just referenced something from a college clinical psychology course. I am not sure why this is arrogant however, care to elaborate? (Again I am just referencing a lecture where job categorization was done in such a way, to make it clear what sectors I am interested in). I am still learning the ropes so care to fix my statement and again, please elaborate on why it is arrogant. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, employers look at any period of time when you were not employed with skepticism.

Job application can be looked at, as if you are looking for a short-term "storm weathering" spot until you can go back to do your own thing

When returning to the work-force be ready for questions like
"if it was so good why do you need a job now?"
etc

Comment: I mean I try to be honest and transparent, it's only good in certain intervals / periods that you are trained and familiarized with, those periods don't last for ever, and so I am looking for a slice of life where the job market is relatively fast paced.

Comment: @blazg_7S, As a general rule, it's good to be honest and transparent, but there is no need to be too honest and too transparent. Truth can have many layers. And it may not be in your best interest to always disclose everything about how you've made these types of decisions in the past.